# Mixed JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript

In the console I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array[3]
  0: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  columns: Array[2]
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

The last item hasn't an index, but the name `columns`.

How can I reproduce something similar?
I tried:

```
var columns = ["age", "population"];
var myObj = [
  {age: "<5",     population: 2704659},
  {age: "5-13",  population: 4499890},
  {age: "14-17", population: 2159981},
  columns
];
console.log(myObj);
```

But it gives me this:

```
// Console
Array[4]
  0: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  3: Array[2]
  length: 4
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

An array is actually just an object that you can attach properties to like any other.

You should avoid adding properties like this though.

```js
var columns = ["age", "population"];
var myObj = [
  {age: "<5",     population: 2704659},
  {age: "5-13",  population: 4499890},
  {age: "14-17", population: 2159981}
];

myObj.columns = columns

console.dir(myObj); // check the browsers actual console to see the output

// this proves that Array inherit's from Object
console.log(myObj instanceof Array)
console.log(myObj instanceof Object)
```

I think you are better off creating your own object of a `Table` that has the different properties with accessors for when you need them.

```js
// define the Table class
class Table {
  constructor(columns, rows) {
    this.columns = columns
    this.rows = rows
  }
  getColumns() {
    return this.columns
  }
  getRows(index) {
    return typeof index !== 'undefined'
      ? this.rows[index]
      : this.rows
  }
  getTable() {
    return [
      this.columns,
      ...this.rows.map(row => Object.values(row))
    ]
  }
}

var columns = ["age", "population"];
var myObj = [
  {age: "<5",     population: 2704659},
  {age: "5-13",  population: 4499890},
  {age: "14-17", population: 2159981}
]

const table = new Table(columns, myObj)

console.log(table)
console.log(table.getColumns())
console.log(table.getRows())
console.log(table.getTable())
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: so `0:Object` it means 0 is  properties ?

Comment: @Mahi Yes, you are right.

Comment: @PraveenKumar so we can make array using `{}`?

Comment: @Mahi yes, but if you are using `{}` you cannot use invalid variable names, where, integers are invalid. `:)`

Comment: @Mahi no, but you can convert an indexed object to an array with `Array.prototype.slice.call(obj)` If you need to iterate over something you should use an array. If you need property accessors you should use an object.